# Get Line Items in an Invoice logic hook in SuiteCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Via a logic hook I'm trying to update fields of my products, after an invoice has been saved.

What I understand so far is, that I need to get the invoice related AOS_Products_Quotes and from there I could get the products, update the required fields and save the products. Does that sound about right?

The logic hook is being triggered but relationships won't load.

```
  function decrement_stocks ( $bean, $event, $arguments) {
   //$bean->product_value_c = $bean->$product_unit_price * $bean->product_qty;

    $file = 'custom/modules/AOS_Invoices/decrement.txt';

    // Get the Invoice ID:
    $sInvoiceID = $bean->id;
    $oInvoice = new AOS_Invoices();
    $oInvoice->retrieve($sInvoiceID);
    $oInvoice->load_relationship('aos_invoices_aos_product_quotes');
    $aProductQuotes = $oInvoice->aos_invoices_aos_product_quotes->getBeans();

    /*
    $aLineItemslist = array();
    foreach ($oInvoice->aos_invoices_aos_product_quotes->getBeans() as $lineitem) {
        $aLineItemslist[$lineitem->id] = $lineitem;
    }
    */
    $sBean = var_export($bean, true);
    $sInvoice = var_export($oInvoice, true);
    $sProductQuotes = var_export($aProductQuotes, true);

    $current = $sProductQuotes . "\n\n\n------\n\n\n" . $sInvoice . "\n\n\n------\n\n\n" . $sBean;

    file_put_contents($file, $current);

  }
```

The invoice is being retrieved just fine. But either `load_relationship` isn't doing anything ($sInvoice isn't changing with or without it) and `$aProductQuotes` is Null.

I'm working on SuiteCRM 7.8.3 and tried it on 7.9.1 as well without success. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SuiteCRM specifics, however I'd always suggest to check:

- Return value of retrieve(): bean or *null*?
  If *null*, then no bean with the given ID was found.
  In such case $oInvoice would stay empty (Your comment suggests that's not the case here though)
- Return value of load_relationship(): *true* (success) or *false* (failure, check logs)

And I do wonder, why don't you use $bean?

Instead you seem to receive another copy/reference of $bean (and calling it $oInvoice)? Why?
Or did you mean to receive a *different type* bean that is somehow connected to $bean?

Then its surely doesn't have the same *id* as $bean, unless you specifically coded it that way.